# GWT - JavaScript Overlay Types and JSON

Tags: gwt, types, overlay

I was the Google Codeing Basics (http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html#example-collections) and thought: hey this could be way faster and easier to use than pharsing my JSON object by hand.

So I played with the example and noticed that it worked fine when the JsArray was defined in the HTML file but I couldn't find a solution to pass a String or Url into the function and it returns me an Overlay Type.

So what I want to do is:

I have this function

```
    private native Customer getFirstCustomer(/*TYPE (preferd String)*/ name) /*-{
    return (CASTVALUE TO ???) name; 
}-*/;
```

To which I pass

```
{"FirstName": "Jimmy"}
```

as String, and It returns me a Java Object like this:

```
    import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;
    class Customer extends JavaScriptObject {
      protected Customer() { }
      public final native String getFirstName() /*-{ return this.FirstName; }-*/;
    }
```

Is this possible?

Best regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Please, do not, by any mean, `eval()` things blindly!** (security 101)

Use GWT's [JsonUtils](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsonUtils.html) instead: it'll use native JSON support in browsers that support it (faster and safer than `eval()`) and will validate the JSON before `eval()`ing it in others (that is, IE6, IE7 and old Safaris –pre 4.0.3–, all other browser versions without native JSON are dead by now):

```
Customer customer = JsonUtils.safeEval(jsonString);
```

Comment: I'll add the JsonUtils to my post :) (I didn't include any security warning in it... I've assumed the json string was controlled beforehand)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a JSON string, in order to create the javscript object, [you must eval it](http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSON.html#parsing):

```
private native Customer getFirstCustomer(String jsonString) /*-{
    return eval(jsonString);
}-*/;
```

If your native method returns your Customer class (it must extends JavaScriptObject) it will be casted automagically (the Java compiler will accept it, in JS it will not need casting).

See [this reference](http://code.google.com/intl/en/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html) too.

**Important security update:**

*Thanks to Thomas Broyer*

Don't use `eval` directly. Use `JsonUtils.safeEval(String)` ([API](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsonUtils.html)). It will avoid executing unsafe javascript code that could come in the string.

```
private native Customer getFirstCustomer(String jsonString) /*-{
    return JsonUtils.safeEval(jsonString);
}-*/;
```

Comment: thanks, in that case it must go to Thomas.... I was wondering about it at night too......